# How spaghettification is possible at the Event Horizon of a supermassive black hole?

Tags: gravity, fundamental-astronomy, supermassive-black-hole, high-energy-astrophysics, quantum-mechanics

if gravity is too strong then it will break a object apart as gravity is strong enough to break the chemical composition of object why we consider "Spaghettification" relevant in this case ?

Comment: Spaghettification is not possible at the event horizon of a SMBH because the tidal forces are not strong enough. If the black hole is, say, 1 solar mass, then objects would be spaghettified before entry into the event horizon.

Comment: I am not an astronomer, but my understanding is that spaghettification is the phrase describing strong *tidal* forces rather than strong *gravity*. In this context the tidal force is the difference in gravity between two points relatively close to each other (such as the head and the toes of the astronaut falling into a black hole). Basically the derivative of gravity (as a function of the distance). There is no need for the tidal forces to be strong at the event horizon when the event horizon is far out (for a suitable definition of *far out*).